# Powershell add column to CSV

Tags: powershell

I did create this powershell script to read out our Security groups and OU members. I want to make my script what more advanced because i export all my request to a .txt.

Now i change the Office request to .csv. But when i run this script the next request won't go to the next colum of the .csv. It replace the first request.

Does some one know how i can solve this problem or can send me an article how I can do this.

```
function Export-UsersToTxt ([string]$OU,[string]$FileName) {
    $Users = Get-ADUser -SearchScope OneLevel -Searchbase $OU -Filter * -ResultSetSize 5000 
    $Users.Count | Out-File $FileName 
    $Users.Name | Out-File $FileName -Append
}

function Export-UsersToOffice ([string]$Office,[string]$OfficeFileName) {
    $OfficeAD = Get-ADGroupMember -identity $Office 
    $OfficeAD.Count | Out-File $OfficeFileName 
    $OfficeAD.Name | Out-File $OfficeFileName -Append
}

#Export Customer
Export-UsersToTxt 'OU=Users,OU=0001_Customer,OU=JdsHosting,DC=jdsontzorgt,DC=local' 'C:\JDS\test\users\Customer Users.txt'
Export-UsersToTxt 'OU=MailboxOnly,OU=Users,OU=0001_Customer,OU=JdsHosting,DC=jdsontzorgt,DC=local' 'C:\JDS\test\users\Customer MailboxOnly.txt'
Export-UsersToTxt 'OU=SharedMailbox,OU=Users,OU=0001_Customer,OU=JdsHosting,DC=jdsontzorgt,DC=local' 'C:\JDS\test\users\Customer Shared Mailbox.txt'
Export-UsersToOffice '0001_App_office' 'C:\JDS\test\users\Office.CSV'

#Export Customer
Export-UsersToTxt 'OU=Users,OU=0002_Customer,OU=JdsHosting,DC=jdsontzorgt,DC=local' 'C:\JDS\test\users\Customer Users.txt'
Export-UsersToTxt 'OU=MailboxOnly,OU=Users,OU=0002_Customer,OU=JdsHosting,DC=jdsontzorgt,DC=local' 'C:\JDS\test\users\Customer MailboxOnly.txt'
Export-UsersToTxt 'OU=SharedMailbox,OU=Users,OU=0002_Customer,OU=JdsHosting,DC=jdsontzorgt,DC=local' 'C:\JDS\test\users\Customer SharedMailbox.txt'
Export-UsersToOffice '0002_App_office' 'C:\JDS\test\users\Office.CSV'
```

Comment: Have a look at the command Export-Csv https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-6

Comment: Looks like you forgot to add -Append to some of your Out-Files.